# SQL queries in BASH script

Tags: sql, bash, variables, hive

I am using Hadoop to execute my queries.

What I want is using BASH variables within my query. Here is an example :

```
export month="date +%m"
export year="date +%Y"

beeline -u jdbc:hive2://clustername.azurehdinsight.net:443/tab' 
-n myname -e "select * from mytable where month = '$month' and  
year = '$year';"
```

But the query is empty so that in reality, it's not the case within Hive.

```
select * from mytable where month = '$month' and  
year = '$year';
```

is not an empty query in Hive.

Is there a problem in my bash script ?

Comment: There should be some function in SQL you can use to get the current date (if not the current month and year specifically), rather than injecting values into the query from the shell.

Comment: Can you show how you run the command when you demonstrate that the query result is not empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need execute `date` command using `$()`, change

```
export month="date +%m"
export year="date +%Y"
```

with

```
export month=$(date +%m)
export year=$(date +%Y)
```

You can use `hivevar` arguments with beeline

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://clustername.azurehdinsight.net:443/tab \
-n myname \
--hivevar month=$month \
--hivevar year=$year \
-e "select * from mytable where month = '${hivevar:month}' and year = '${hivevar:year}';"
```

Comment: I think you need to single quote the query or escape the `$`, otherwise, bash will try to expand it before hive does.

Comment: Your variable contains `date command` instead of result of the command

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: your variable `month` contain `date +%m`, instead of `08`

Comment: your variable `year` contain `date +%Y`, instead of `2018`

Comment: Before you changed my variable, it contained the value and not the command.

Comment: When you execute `export year="date +%Y"` and then `echo $year` you don't see `2018` ; But with `export year=$(date +%Y)` it will works.